# Pycharm: how to change all color include project tree

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, themes

So i download the `plugin` One Dark and set it as my `theme`:

[image]

And as you can see this change my editor `color` but the `color` of the `Left panel/Project tree` remain the same and i did not find any way to change it to the same `color`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Theme**:

[image]